# Disable send Zipkin spans on Pilot

Tags: istio, distributed-tracing

How can I disable Istio to send spans to zipkin?

If I'm not wrong this is not a mixer adapter right? It is something directly done from the pilot.

How can I disable it?

Answer (score 0):

According to [the section titled Cleanup in the Istio docs](https://istio.io/docs/tasks/telemetry/distributed-tracing.html):

```
kubectl delete -f install/kubernetes/addons/zipkin.yaml
```

Comment: That is to remove the zipkin containers, but what about the pilot configuration? My understanding is that pilot perform some action about spans reporting and send them to zipkin. Is that configuration automatically stoped if zipkin containers are not installed?

Comment: @Jxadro I don't know. But my assumption would be yes. Have you tried?

Comment: How can I know if it works? How do I know if pilot is working on it?

Comment: @Jxadro Sorry, I am not familiar enough with Istio to answer that. I'd just run the command given in the docs and be done with it.